What does the Rainworld Remix add?
In the main menu of Rainworld (on Nintendo Switch, I don't know if it's on the PC version), there is a Remix section where you can enable mods/DLCs.
One of those mods is called Rainworld Remix.
Its description:

A wide variety of configurable accessibility features and community requested features, including new gameplay mechanics and bonus features. Use the configuration screen to toggle individual features on or off.

What exactly does it add though?

This should be the list of features you can set in Remix that I found on Reddit:

More info here.
